# How to insert list of lists (table) into wx.grid?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a list of lists, in the same form you'd insert into CSV. I want to insert all of this data into a wx.grid.Grid().

I think the process is like this.

```
data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
myTable = someFunc(data)
myGrid.SetTable(myTable)
```

Can anyone help me out? I'm not quite sure how to make myTable from my list of lists. I couldn't find much on Google, Stack Exchange or GitHub.

Is the only way to do this to loop every cell with SetCellValue(self, row, col, s)?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, the only way is to set each cell explicitly.  I guess you read all this stuff here? http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxGrid